# Having audio issue on Dell XPS

Tags: windows-vista, audio, dell-xps

My os is vista and my audio was going in and out, I would have to enable it for it to come back on, so I set it to enable automatic whenever the audio does crash, it still gave me problems because when the audio went out, everything using audio would have to be restarted in order to hear the volume again even though the audio was already back enabled.  When audio goes out I receive a "host process for windows services stop working popup message" . could someone tell me what kind of issue is this, I went to my device manager to try a driver update or scan for hardware changes for audio, but it doesnt seem to fix the problem. Just to see if it was the actual internal speakers I hooked up the audio output to external speakers and get the same results.Can someone help me.... model-M1530

Comment: is it still not working?

Answer (score 1):

A friend of me had the same problem and fixed it by downloading the newest drivers from http://support.dell.com. If this doesn't work: please check your Event-log by first pressing Windows-Key + R, then enter eventvwr.exe and press ok. Check specially Windows-log - System.

But when did you buy your laptop? if the laptop is not older then half a year, you can get an update to windows seven for free at https://win7.dell.com/Eligibility.aspx

Comment: its older than half a year, and my event log does not work, I took a look at it and its not running

Comment: didnt fix the issue fter downloading the new updated oftware from the support site